# Is 2's complement the only way that singed binary numbers are represented?

Tags: binary

I have only seen mention 2's complement practically everytime signed number representation is mentioned. However, I have found that there are other ways to represent signed numbers also, these are 1's complement, excess-k and base -2.

Except 1's complement I do not really understand how the other two work. However, what I want to know is, are these other representations ever used at all? If so, where and why? I know that the strength of 2's complement is that addition and subtraction become the same. However, I am not sure about the strengths of the other mentioned methods.

Comment: You need a textbook, I think.

Comment: which textbook?

Comment: In the dominant IEEE P754 standard for floating point numbers, sign&magnitude is used for the mantissa (aka significand) and excess- for the exponent. S&M is a bit simpler with rounding, has no asymmetry (-128... +127 in 8bits two's complement, which is a pain for operations as multiplications and divisions...), how while excess- allows continuity between small exponents and zero which is represented with zeros.

Comment: There _were_ a lot of different ideas tried in the past. But a **_huge_** advantage for twos complement comes in the implementation details of add/subtract hardware logic. Some early Russian computers even used balanced trinary. But that was a long time back, as well. The world has explored the options and, for mainstream computing work, has settled on twos complement notation. For integers. Floating point is a different problem, entirely. Normalization, easy ordering, and other factors play there. So it's handled differently. You probably do need an historical book for details about 'why'.

Comment: What do you know? Wiki has a page that may help (if you haven't already been there): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations It discusses some of your questions. Perhaps not all. But it does more than I'd want to replicate here.

Comment: The Apollo Guidance Computer used 1's complement IIRC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### We all float on again...right back into the land of sign-magnitude numbers!

Twos' complement is *almost* universally used for integer arithmetic for the exact reasons you stated -- addition and subtraction work the same way, carries behave sensibly, and signed overflow is easy to detect as well.

However, *floating point* math almost universally uses sign-magnitude representation for the overall number, primarily to ease rounding considerations and remove asymmetries in significand range.  The only machines that *don't* use sign-magnitude representation for floating point are of the prehistoric type (even things like S/360s, VAXen, and Crays that predate IEEE 754 use sign-magnitude FP).  However, the ubiquity of sign-magnitude IEEE 754 FP has had an impact on *integer* arithmetic as well, thanks to Brendan Eich's little project called JavaScript.

You see, JavaScript's *only* arithmetic type is the IEEE 754 double precision float; thankfully, IEEE 754 floats can represent integers exactly up to the significand width.  The one problem with this, though, is that using IEEE 754 floats for integer math means you are stuck with sign-magnitude integer math!  That's right, negative integers work differently in JavaScript than in *every other modern language*.  Think about this the next time you hear someone pitching Node.js...

Comment: Is sign extension when shifting the only important issue to be careful about when using 2's complement or there are others too? I am talking about special considerations here which if not kept in mind will cause failure.

Comment: Sign extension on right shifts is pretty much it, unless you're implementing a signed multiply/divide block...

Comment: Yes, I need to carry out multiplication.

Comment: Hmm it seems I need sign extension of operands to twice the operand bit length before doing multiplication